# Impossible Schur Factorizations

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, numerical-linear-algebra, matrix-decomposition, schur-decomposition

I am having trouble finding the schur factorization of the following matrix:

$A=\begin{pmatrix}3&8 \\ -2&3 \end{pmatrix}$

I followed an algorithm in the book, as well as computing an answer via Octave/Matlab. I did the following:

[U,T] = schur(A) where $U$ will be a unitary matrix and $T$ will be an upper triangular matrix.

Which gave me:

$U=\begin{pmatrix}1&0 \\ 0&1 \end{pmatrix}$
and
$T=A$

$T=A$ is not upper triangular -- schur's factorization is supposed to give us an upper triangular matrix...

1. What went wrong? Is a schur factorization possible for every square matrix (it should be according to [wikipedia on schur decomposition](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Schur_factorization)

Thanks for all the help!

Comment: No, I get the exact same result...

Comment: No luck :( I even tried .000001 difference...

Comment: So, from your value of Q we were able to recover the value of U and indeed got an upper triangular matrix. What are you using, or how did you do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Matlab's [documentation](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/schur.html) for `schur` does not state that `T` is triangular, but rather "quasitriangular". Quasitriangular matrices are a special form of [Hessenberg matrix](http://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hessenberg_matrix).

By default, the `schur` function returns the real form of the decomposition. Because your `A` matrix [has complex eigenvalues](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Matrix_decomposition#Schur_decomposition) the real Schur matrix `T` will be quasitriangular instead of upper triangular.

You can compute the more general complex Schur form as @Amzoti suggests via:

```
A = [3 8;-2 3];
[U,T] = schur(A,'complex')
```

which returns

```
U =

   0.0000 + 0.8944i   0.4472 + 0.0000i
  -0.4472 + 0.0000i   0.0000 - 0.8944i


T =

   3.0000 + 4.0000i  -6.0000 + 0.0000i
   0.0000 + 0.0000i   3.0000 - 4.0000i
```

In this case `T` is guaranteed to be diagonal.

By the way, you can convert the real matrix `A` to a complex one with a zero imaginary part by using the [`complex`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/complex.html) function (simply adding `0*1i` generally won't work). Thus the following could also be used:

```
A = [3 8;-2 3];
[U,T] = schur(complex(A))
```

Comment: What about solving this out by hand?